# How can I read a config file from airflow packaged DAG?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Airflow [packaged DAGs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#packaged-dags) seem like a great building block for a sane production airflow deployment.

I have a DAG with dynamic subDAGs, driven by a config file, something like:

config.yaml:

```
imports:
  - project_foo
  - project_bar`
```

which yields subdag tasks like `imports.project_{foo|bar}.step{1|2|3}`.

I've normally read in the config file using python's `open` function, a la `config = open(os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 'config.yaml')`

Unfortunately, when using packaged DAGs, this results in an error:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/dags/workflows.zip] [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/airflow/dags/workflows.zip/config.yaml'
```

Any thoughts / best practices to recommend here?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a kludge, but I eventually just fell back on reading zip file contents via `ZipFile`.

```
import yaml
from zipfile import ZipFile
import logging
import re

def get_config(yaml_filename):
  """Parses and returns the given YAML config file.

  For packaged DAGs, gracefully handles unzipping.
  """
  zip, post_zip = re.search(r'(.*\.zip)?(.*)', yaml_filename).groups()
  if zip:
    contents = ZipFile(zip).read(post_zip.lstrip('/'))
  else:
    contents = open(post_zip).read()
  result = yaml.safe_load(contents)
  logging.info('Parsed config: %s', result)
  return result
```

which works as you'd expect from the main `dag.py`:

```
get_config(os.path.join(path.split(__file__)[0], 'config.yaml'))
```

Comment: Is this still the only way? :(